# htaccess rule to rename .php to .html is interfering with other rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to change all .php files to .html extensions and the rule I am using is interfering with other rules in my .htaccess file.  It appears that I can either get one set of rules to work or the other.

Check the code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

##Locations Pages
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)\.html?$                           locations.php?locationslug=$1&Submit=Submit                 [L]

##Listing Pages
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)\/([^/\.]+)\.html?$                listings.php?locationslug=$1&categoryslug=$2                [L]

##Vendor Pages
RewriteRule    ^([^/\.]+)\/([^/\.]+)\/([^/\.]+)\.html?$     vendors2.php?vendorslug=$3&locationslug=$1&categoryslug=$2  [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

If I put the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]` as the 3rd line of the file, the flat .php pages work as .html however, the following rules throw an error (404 Not Found).

If I put the line `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]` as the last line, the flat pages will not work as .html.

As always, any constructive input is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of these rules from most specific to most generic ones like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

##Vendor Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$ vendors2.php?vendorslug=$3&locationslug=$1&categoryslug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

##Listing Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$ listings.php?locationslug=$1&categoryslug=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html?$ $1.php [L,NC]

##Locations Pages
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html?$ locations.php?locationslug=$1&Submit=Submit [L,QSA,NC]
```

Just fyi that your rule # 3 and 4 will both match same URI pattern.